# error importing basemap in spyder

Tags: python, windows, spyder, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to import basemap in spyder on a windows machine (64bit, Python34) but I'm getting the following error:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-5e6824321d57>", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

ImportError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

I'm quite puzzled because I can import it just fine in Python's IDLE. I just can't import it in Spyder. Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you changed your Python interpreter in the past. Please take a look at what option you have selected in `Tools > Preferences > Console > Advanced Settings > Python executable`, and make sure it's using the `Default` value.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the reply. I checked but my settings are on the default value and I'm still experiencing the same issue. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you have several Python installations? Sorry, but it's hard to help you with such little info.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. In my case `basemap` was not included in `mpl_toolkits`. You should find a folder named `basemap` here:
`...\Python\python-3.4.4\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\`
If not, you may download the basemap-package from [this repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
and install it with `python -m pip install packagename`

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still active.
I had same problem several times now with different modules. Usually I would create new environement, install some module, open spyder, try importing module and error appears.But if I open Python in terminal within same environement, import module works.
I'm no expert to say what is behind it, but I noticed the differece in Python version when I open spyder and when I open it from terminal.
Solution that worked each time: conda install spyder, in this new environement. It seems otherwise, spyder that opens is not really connected to new environement.
Maybe someone can give more technical answer why it is so, but I hope this answer will help someone :) cheers